# MySQL: Get latest message from 2 tables that are associated with eachother

Tags: mysql, sql

First, thank you so much for your help.

I have 2 tables: a `conversation` table and a `message` table, and a third table `assoc_message__conversation` that associates the messages to a conversation.

I need to get the latest `message_id` and `message` sent for each conversation specified, along with the `conversation_id` it is associated with.

Here is a db-fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kxRQeGUYYgQ7FTwi96hbLp/0

As you can see in this example, there are two conversations with `conversation_id` of 1 and 2, and there are three messages associated to each conversation. Messages 1, 2, and 3 are associated to conversation 1, and messages 4, 5 and 6 are associated to conversation 2.

I need to be able to specify the `conversation_id`'s in the `assoc_message__conversation` table (IDs 1 and 2), and retrieve the latest `message_id`, `message` and the associated `conversation_id` sent from the `message` table for each conversation specified.

So the rows it should pull are:

```
conversation_id | message_id | message
------------------------------------------------
              1 |          3 | "Latest message"
------------------------------------------------
              2 |          6 | "Latest message"
------------------------------------------------
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the fiddle, but your question should stand on its own two foot directly here on Stack Overflow.  Currently, it does not, because you gave no table structure, or sample input/output data.  Please include these for best results.

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you for your comment. The fiddle does include the CREATE TABLE statement and the INSERT statement which includes the data.

Comment: That information belongs in your question, not as an external link, at least not as an external link alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In older versions of MySQL (< 8.0.2), we can use [Derived Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html). In a Derived table, we can get the latest `send_datetime` value for each `conversation_id`. **Also, it is noteworthy that you can provide your filters for conversation_id in the `WHERE` clause of this subquery.**

We can then use this subquery`s result-set and join back to the main tables appropriately, to get the row corresponding to the latest message in a conversation.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kxRQeGUYYgQ7FTwi96hbLp/1)

**Query #1**

```
SELECT
  amc.conversation_id, 
  m.message_id, 
  m.message   
FROM 
  assoc_message__conversation AS amc
JOIN message AS m 
  ON m.message_id = amc.message_id 
JOIN 
(
  SELECT
    amc1.conversation_id, 
    MAX(m1.send_datetime) AS latest_send_datetime
  FROM
   assoc_message__conversation AS amc1
  JOIN message AS m1
    ON m1.message_id = amc1.message_id 
  WHERE amc1.conversation_id IN (1,2)  -- Here you provide your input filters
  GROUP BY amc1.conversation_id
) AS dt  
  ON dt.conversation_id = amc.conversation_id AND 
     dt.latest_send_datetime = m.send_datetime;
```

**Result**

```
| conversation_id | message_id | message        |
| --------------- | ---------- | -------------- |
| 1               | 3          | Latest message |
| 2               | 6          | Latest message |
```

---

In MySQL 8.0.2 and above, we can use `Row_Number()` functionality. Within a partition of `conversation_id`, we will determine Row Number for every message, sorted in descending order of `send_datetime`. **In this subquery, you can provide your filters for conversation_id in the `WHERE` clause.**

We will then use this result-set as a Derived Table, and consider only those rows, where Row Number value is 1 (as it will belong to latest `send_datetime`).

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kxRQeGUYYgQ7FTwi96hbLp/2)

**Query #2**

```
SELECT 
  dt.conversation_id, 
  dt.message_id, 
  dt.message 
FROM 
(
  SELECT
    amc.conversation_id, 
    m.message_id, 
    m.message, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY amc.conversation_id 
                       ORDER BY m.send_datetime DESC) AS row_no 
  FROM
   assoc_message__conversation AS amc
  JOIN message AS m
    ON m.message_id = amc.message_id 
  WHERE amc.conversation_id IN (1,2)  -- Here you provide your input filters
) AS dt  
WHERE dt.row_no = 1;
```

**Result**

```
| conversation_id | message_id | message        |
| --------------- | ---------- | -------------- |
| 1               | 3          | Latest message |
| 2               | 6          | Latest message |
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer @Madhur Byaiya. I tested the query with 1.7M rows of messages and it ran in 0.01 seconds, where as the other answer took over 14 seconds to run!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `amc_id` increments for each new message, I would recommend a correlated subquery in the `where` clause:

```
select amc.*, m.message
from message m join
     assoc_message__conversation amc
     on amc.message_id = m.message_id
where amc.amc_id = (select max(amc.amc_id)
                    from assoc_message__conversation amc2
                    where amc2.conversation_id = amc.conversation_id
                   );
```

If you actually need to use `send_datetime`, then an additional `join` is necessary:

```
where m.send_datetime = (select max(m2.send_datetime)
                         from message m2 join
                              assoc_message__conversation amc2
                              on amc2.message_id = m2.message_id
                         where amc2.conversation_id = amc.conversation_id
                        )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Gordon. This query seems to pull all of the messages. I need to be able to specify which conversations I want to retrieve the latest messages for. Example, in my db-fiddle there are 2 conversations, IDs 1 and 2. So i need to be able to specify conversations 1 and/or 2, and only retrieve the latest message for each conversation.

Comment: @PHPMYSQLDEV . . . Then you would have a `where` clause in the outer query specifying the conversations you want.